# Difference between Wakelock and Activity Flag_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

Tags: android

You can keep your screen awake in Android through two ways. I have read this thread [Difference between Wakelock and FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376902/difference-between-wakelock-and-flag-keep-screen-on)

```
mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, 
            getClass().getName());
```

Or by adding the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON to the activity,

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

That Answer did not cover all the points where you should use which one. I am looking for the same

Comment: Writing code takes much time. On many sites you can find many and many examples. You can use wakelock also in service.

Comment: WakeLock => Out from your activity too, flags => only when you are working in the activity